# how to apply responsive style in React jsx?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I apply a responsive style to suspect elements inside the jsx style tag on my react project.
Here is some code for that.

```
<div>
  <img
    className="image"
    src={resizedUrl}
    width={params.width}
    height={params.height}
    style={{ ...shadowStyle }} />
  <div className="time">{photo.photo.published_at}</div>
  <div className="article-title" style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
    {photo.photo.title}
    <label className="feed">{photo.photo.feed_name}</label>
  </div>
  <div className="article-description">
    {photo.photo.short_description}
  </div>
</div>
...
<style jsx>{`
  .article-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000000;
    display: -webkit-box;
    line-height: 1.2;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  @media (max-width: 768px) .article-description {
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 48;
    color: black;
    display: -webkit-box;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.2;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
`}</style>
```

I just gonna apply resposive style for the article-description, but my code is not working now.
Please share your solution to apply that inside the jsx style on React.

Cheers.

Comment: Wrap `@media` contents in `{` and `}`?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand you correctly.
Would you please describe in more detail?

Comment: See Andy Hoffman's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restructure your media query, which is syntactically invalid, to encapsulate all styles for that breakpoint.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .article-description {
      font-weight: 700;
      height: 48;
      color: black;
      display: -webkit-box;
      padding: 5px;
      display: block;
      line-height: 1.2;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    .something-else { … }
  }
```